# Complex wordpress menu layout

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

I am creating a wordpress page with complex menu layout system.
This is a first for me to get stuck with menu.
My menu virtually looks like this, looks simple.

```
-main_menu_item's
--main_menu_subitem's
---main_menu_subitem2's
```

but, my site structure is not that easy.

I have **horizontal -main_menu_item's** on top of page, 
after that there is slider and after slider comes **horizontal main_menu_subitem's**.
Now comes content part of **--main_menu_subitem's** and if it has **---main_menu_subitem2's** they will be displayed on sidebar.

My problem is that how can i break one menu into three different blocks of code that i can display in different places?

```
MAIN MENU
-main_menu_item
______________________________________________________________________

SLIDER
SLIDER
______________________________________________________________________
SUBMENU OF MAIN MENU
--main_menu_subitem --main_menu_subitem --main_menu_subitem
______________________________________________________________________
IF SUBMENU HAVE ITEMS, ELSE ONLY CONTENT

---main_menu_subitem2 | content area
---main_menu_subitem2 | content area
---main_menu_subitem2 | content area
```

So, anyone seeing this easy and would like to give me a hand on this?

Comment: Now wordpress by default has a menu system. You could create three different menus  and add fetch them separately at different locations

Comment: Yes, i could, but **--main_menu_subitem** changes according to top level item and is not same all the time. All sub-levels are related to top level active menu item. e.g: if top level menu name is **CARS** then sub-level changes too. On top of the page I wrote out my menu structure.

Comment: Ok now that seems complex, so bascilly you have a Parent if it changes then the child and also the grandchildren changes. Also if the child is changed then the grandchildren will change. hmmm could be done by coding using current instance ids.

Comment: are all items in the menu pages, and have parents selected as per they will appear in the menu? or is this a hierarchy of categories?

Comment: All menu items are pages with parents.

Comment: So basically if C is a page then B is set as its parent and similarly A is set as parent of B. A will be listed in the menu above the slider. B will be listed below the slider and C in the sidebar.

Now you could achieve this in two ways. Create a wordpress navigation menu for the main menu above the slider. Next when one from the above is selected, you get the current page id, depending on that load the exact childs in the menu below the slider. Similarly for the sidebar menus.

Comment: Also there could be a possibility of first load when no exact values are being fetched then you could possibly use the first values for each subsequent listing.

Comment: Ok, added top menu with wordpress function. Added under slider children query like this:

    $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post-    >ID.'&echo=0&depth=1');

Comment: Can you create an example for all of this starting from under slider menu query?